# Howto correctly bind RibbonGalleryCategory to a collection

Tags: xaml, data-binding, ribbon

I'm using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.

I want to have a dynamic combobox with picture buttons in my ribbon.

If I do this directly in xaml, I get what I want:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox 
                      SelectionBoxWidth="62"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      >
                    <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="0"
                      SelectedValuePath="Content"
                      MaxColumnCount="1">
                        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                            <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Histo"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Command="{Binding NewHistogrammCommand}" 
                                       SmallImageSource="/Test;component/Resourcen/Histogramm32.png" 
                                       LargeImageSource="/Test;component/Resourcen/Histogramm32.png" />
                            <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="3D"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Command="{Binding NewDreiDCommand}" 
                                       SmallImageSource="/Test;component/Resourcen/DreiD32.png" 
                                       LargeImageSource="/Test;component/Resourcen/DreiD32.png" />
                        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
                </ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

But if I try to do this via binding to a collection this way:

```
                    <ribbon:RibbonComboBox 
                      SelectionBoxWidth="62"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      IsEditable="True" >
                    <ribbon:RibbonGallery
                      MaxColumnCount="1">
                        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding LayoutContentTypeList, ElementName=mainWindow}">
                            <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Header}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                           Command="{Binding Command}" 
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" 
                                           SmallImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                           LargeImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
                </ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

I get

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsDropDownOpen' property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target element is 'RibbonButton' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

The buttons work correctly, but how can I resolve this binding error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you've found a solution for your problem, but for other people coming across this post, looking for an answer, you can find a complete solution that you can download and examine at your leisure in the [How do I add Galleries to my Ribbon?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/how-do-i-add-galleries-to-my-ribbon.aspx) post at 'The official blog of the Windows Presentation Foundation Team'. The basic idea is as follows.

Whatever object that you set as the `RibbonGallery.DataContext` should have a collection property to bind to the `RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsSource` property. The objects in that collection should have properties containing the values that you want to appear in the gallery items. Declare a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `RibbonGallery.CategoryTemplate` to bind your properties. Here is an example from the linked post:

```
<Ribbon:RibbonGallery DataContext="{x:Static data:WordModel.StylesParagraphGalleryData}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryDataCollection}" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Ribbon:RibbonGallery.CategoryTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding GalleryItemDataCollection}">
            <Border Background="LightGray">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Border>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images\Paragraph_32x32.png" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Ribbon:RibbonGallery.CategoryTemplate>
</Ribbon:RibbonGallery>
```